# error "not enough arguments given" when setting a function of a class as a callback

Tags: python-2.7, function, websocket

I'm new to python. Following is my code. I get this error when I create an instance of my class.

***error from callback >: on_open() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)***

The same code works alright if I do all of this outside the Class, directly in the main file. I think it has something to do with the 'self' thing(attribute ?). But the similar code on the server side works alright.
I'm using this [web-socket-client package](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)! and following the example **Long-lived connection** shown there.

This is the [library](https://github.com/Pithikos/python-websocket-server)! I'm using for the server side, which has pretty similar interface as the client library.

**Server Side Code**

```
from websocket_server import WebsocketServer

def client_connected(client, server):
    print "connected:"
    print client

def client_disconnected(client, server):
    print "Disconnected:"
    print client

def message_received(client, server, message):
    server.send_message(client, message)
    print "message received: ", message
    print client

server = WebsocketServer(13254, host='127.0.0.1')
server.set_fn_new_client(client_connected)
server.set_fn_client_left(client_disconnected)
server.set_fn_message_received(message_received)
server.run_forever()
```

**Client Side code that works.**

```
import websocket
from multiprocessing import Lock
import copy
import json
import time
import thread

txMsg = "hello world"
def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def on_open(ws):
    def run():
        for i in range(1):
            time.sleep(1)
            print txMsg
            ws.send(txMsg)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print "thread terminating..."
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://127.0.0.1:13254",
                                on_message = on_message,
                                on_error = on_error,
                                on_close = on_close,
                        on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

**Client side code that produces error**

```
import websocket

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Client:
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    serverAddress = None
    serverPort = None
    socket = None

    def __init__(self, serverAddress, serverPort):
        self.serverAddress= serverAddress
        self.serverPort = serverPort
        websocket.enableTrace(True)
        self.socket = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://"+ serverAddress +":"+str(serverPort),
                            on_message = self.on_message,
                          on_error = self.on_error,
                          on_close = self.on_close,
                          on_open = self.on_open)


# Callbacks------------------------------------------------------------------

    def on_open(self, ws):
        print "***Connection Opened***"
        self.close()
    def on_close(self, ws):
        print "***Connection Closed***"
    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print "Message: ", message
        self.socket.close()
    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print "Error: ", error

# API------------------------------------------------------------------

    def close(self):
        self.socket.close()

client = Client('127.0.0.1', 13254)
client.socket.run_forever()
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, two advises: Firstly, singletons are sometimes considered anti-patterns. Make sure you understand why. Secondly, don't learn Python 2 when Python 3 is out, stable and offers lots of improvements.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I'll add both server and client side codes so that the error can be reproduced. As for python 2, for some reasons I'm bound to use it instead of python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code of the client library, go to "_app.py". In function "_callback" of the class "WebSocketApp" (line 339 at the moment of writing this answer), change

```
if inspect.ismethod(callback):
```

to

```
if not inspect.ismethod(callback):
```